# Can monsters open doors or teleport via glyphs?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

One of my current strategies in Dungeons of Dredmor is to close myself in a room in order to heal.  Sometimes also I'll escape via the Satanic Displacement Glyph system.  Thus far, I've not found any enemies that can get to me when I do one of these things, so I'm assuming when I do them that I'm safe from harm.

However, I'm only on the second level of the dungeon.  (This is the furthest I've ever gotten! wooo!)  Will this strategy eventually fail me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monsters cannot open doors or use the satanic displacement glyph. They can't close doors, either, and they cannot use stairs.

Keep in mind your pets, if you have any, can't do any of these either.

Answer (score 1):

They may not be able to open doors or use those glyphs, but there are some monsters that have the ability to Blink, ie randomly teleport.